# Получение данных с разных форм

Tags: php, html

Есть две формы: в одной поиск, в другой лимитирование вывода результатов.

```html
<form></form>
    <div id="vivod"></div>
<form></form>
```

как послать скрипту параметры из обоих форм при нажатии на сабмит в одной из них?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вторая форма не нужна, можно привязать input'ы, находящиеся за пределами первой формы, к форме, указав в атрибуте form инпута её id 
http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/form

Comment: то что надо!благодарю,а то развели тут демагогию...

Comment: @DarkVss, тогда вопрос ваш не правильно сформирован ;)

Comment: Жаль что IE 10+ ..

Comment: Формы можно вообще уже не использовать =) Дабы избежать ботоводов и кравлеров и лучше на клиенте их рисовать =))

Answer (score -1):

При нажатии любого submit через js забирайте данные со всех полей обеих форм и отправляйте их на сервер через ajax.

Comment: нужно без аякса

Comment: А зачем тогда две формы? Может одной хватит? Тогда и вопрос сам собой отпадет

Comment: если сделать <form><div></div></div>.стили перестают работать.и вообще представления изменяю,и имею дело с конструктором.к стилям нет доступа\

Comment: в этом весь прикол что нужно две..

Comment: Или две формы и ajax, или одна форма и стили. Других вариантов на ум не приходит.

Comment: @Visman, есть третий вариант: скрытая форма, которая содержит все поля обеих форм. При сабмите одной из видимых все данные переносятся в скрытую и сабмитится уже скрытая. Тот же ajax, но уже с извращениями )

Comment: @DarkVss, тогда у вас [XY-problem](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709), вы решаете не ту задачу