# Отправка данных из трёх форм на один url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, synchronized

Есть форма 1 с полями A и B, форма 2 с полями C и D, кнопка отправить находится вне этих форм, у нее есть своя форма 3 с полями E и F.
Задача такая, нужно отправить данные из всех форм по нажатию "отправить" в форме 3.
Что я делаю, я по очереди делаю serialize всех форм, склеиваю все с амперсантом, получаю урл формы 3, делаю $.ajax с установленным async:false (мне нужно сэмулировать обычное нажатие на кнопку, не асинхронный запрос) и получаю

```html
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.
```

Как выйти из ситуации? как мне выполнить задачу?
p.s. ajax асинхронный не предлагать, жестко вырезать поля (html) всех форм, вставлять в форму 3 и отправлять - тоже не предлагать.
Какие есть варианты?

Comment: Можно обойтись без трех форм. Посмотрите на этот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438162/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC/438171#438171 ответ.

Comment: Не понял до конца, т.е. я должен во всех инпутах формы 1 и 2 написать в form атрибутах id 3й формы. и тогда, при нажатии сабмита в 3й форме подхватятся ее данные и данные формы 1 и 2? а при нажатии в форме 1 на сабмит отправятся только ее данные на (ну как обычно) ее урл и так же будет и в форме 2? Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: Про 1й и 2й ни чего не скажу, нужен тест. А про 3й - должен без всяких скриптов отправить все данные.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создавать для этого три формы, как и использовать Javascript — нет необходимости.

Создайте одну и дайте ей атрибут `id="main-form"`. Затем у необходимых полей вне формы задайте атрибут `form="main-form"`.

**Вот пример:**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="A" form="main_form">
    <input type="text" name="B" form="main_form">
</div>

<div>
    <input type="text" name="C" form="main_form">
    <input type="text" name="D" form="main_form">
</div>

<form id="main_form" action="/">
    <input type="text" name="E">
    <input type="text" name="F">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

По нажатию **Send** на сервер отправятся данные из формы и из всех внешних полей, которые привязаны к форме через атрибут `form=""`.