# Отправка данных из множества инпутов, находящихся вне формы

Tags: html, jquery, form, input, отправка

У себя на сайте сделал так, как в примере ([Отправка данных из трёх форм на один url](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439811/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-url/472132#472132)) (правда после двух инпутов есть еще кнопка сабмит), но, есть одно но, когда в первом (или в каком либо еще) инпуте я вхожу не корректные данные, либо просто нажимаю на кнопку отправить, меня автоматом перенаправляет на первый инпут...

Как решить эту проблему?

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" name="A" form="main_form">
    <input type="text" name="B" form="main_form">
</div>

<div>
    <input type="text" name="C" form="main_form">
    <input type="text" name="D" form="main_form">
</div>

<form id="main_form" action="/">
    <input type="text" name="E">
    <input type="text" name="F">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```